# PHP Fatal Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found

Tags: php, linux, apache, mongodb, apache2

I have a site using Apache that is just the following code:

```
<?php $m = new MongoClient(); ?>
```

and when I try to access it, I get the error in error.log

```
`PHP Fatal Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found`
```

The following are settings which might be wrong, but I don't think are.

`php -i | grep 'Configuration'` => `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli | Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

`grep 'mongo' /etc/php5/cli/php.ini` => `extension=mongo.so`

`php -i | grep 'extension'` => 
`extension_dir => /usr/lib/php5/20121212 => /usr/lib/php5/20121212`

`ls /usr/lib/php5/20121212/ | grep 'mongo.so'` => `mongo.so`

I haven't been able to find anything to suggest I installed it wrong or have it wrongly configured. I installed it within the past two hours using `pecl` and `pear` (`sudo pear install -f pecl/mongo` and `sudo pecl install mongo`)

I've restarted my Apache and even my computer multiple times.

So why am I getting the error `Class 'MongoClient' not found`?

I'm on Ubuntu. PHP version 5.5.

Edit: I've just discovered that MongoClient is valid when I run php in interactive mode. Perhaps it has to do with a user permission/user installation issue?

Comment: That question is using XAMPP, which I am not, and the solution ended up being a problem with specifying a .dll, whereas I am on Linux. Additionally, everything the only answer brings up is addressed in my question.

Comment: Check the permissions of `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mongo.so` - they should be the same as the permissions of the other files in the directory. Also you can run `strace` to see what exactly fails when `php` tries to open `mongo.so`. E.g. `strace -f php test.php 2>&1 | grep 20121212`

Comment: @user3584460 Thanks for the response. The permissions were basically the same (664 instead of 644) but I changed them to exactly the same and there is no issue. As for the second part, there appears to be no issue because it works when I'm running it as myself. I think I made the question kind of confusing, as I didn't specify that this is a problem when Apache (user www-data) is running PHP, not when I am.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `php -i | grep 'Configuration'` to find the .ini file. This lead to `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. In retrospect, this should have been an obvious giveaway: `cli` means command line interface, basically for the interpreter. What I needed was the ini file that Apache was using.

Unfortunately, there was no great way to do this as I couldn't log into the `www-data` user, but I made a file that had the code

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

and that revealed that the .ini file location was actually `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.

Once I updated *that* ini file with `extension=mongo.so`, the module was loaded at startup, so I restarted and everything is working now.

Comment: That is 100% true. For me it was: "/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini"

Answer (score 1):

i have done it using following sequence

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb

sudo service mongodb start

mongo

sudo pecl install mongo

cd /build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download

sudo tar zxvf mongo-1.6.8.tgz

cd mongo-1.6.8

sudo phpize

cd ./configure

sudo make install

sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

add extension=mongo.ini inphp.ini

sudo gedit/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mongodb.ini

add extension=mongo.so

sudo service apache2 restart
```

and by the help of following url

http://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/install-php-driver.php

Comment: This looks like you are doing the installation twice.
1) using "sudo pecl install mongo".
2) using "configure, make install".

Secondly, why do you first link the extension from php.ini to mongodb.ini and then add the extension there?